# How to build an Angular Plunker locally

Tags: javascript, angular, plunker

I have create a new Plunker Angular project and have downloaded the code zip file.

I unzipped it but there no instructions on how to run it locally.

In the project folder I have:

```
- config.js
- index.html
- readme.md
src
-style.css
```

How to I set this up to build it locally?

Comment: Why not to use Angular CLI to create new local project and then to use your plunker code in it? That would give you much more convenient start for building the real app...

Comment: Because, Angular CLI uses Webpack and I Plunker uses SystemJs and I want to run it with SystemJs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have explicitly stated that you require to use SystemJS instead of Webpack, you have three options here:

- 1 - use older version of Angular CLI, as the early versions used SystemJS;
- 2 - use old Angular Quickstart available [@GitHub](https://github.com/angular/quickstart), which is using SystemJS;
- 3 - find some tutorial on how to use Angular and SystemJS, such as [this one](https://scotch.io/courses/getting-started-with-angular-2/systemjs)

Note that your Angular code is independent on SystemJS and all your modules, components or whatever is that you created in Plunker should be working in Angular CLI project sporting Webpack. Hence there should be no worries that new Angular CLI versions are using Webpack instead of SystemJS as far as you are interested only in Angular code.

After you have your environment ready, use your Plunker code within it.

Comment: Ref your note... I've tried to code on a project with Angular-CLI All the code works except "System.import"

Comment: Sorry to hear that, but I cannot really tell what is going on in your project without any code insight ...